# Recommended hardware for speech recognition IoT device

Tags: speech-recognition, iot

Hi I need to develop a platform for my bachelors it consist in a device capable of recording voice and use a cloud based solution like Google Cloud Speech API and then send the transcription to a MySQL database.

Thanks for the help.

Omar Gutierrez

Answer (score 0):

Alexa dev kit would be great for development with AWS
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-voice-service/dev-kits
A cheaper device would be any RPI with any far-field microphone array- this would require some more thinking on how to implement your cloud architecture as this would require you to choose your SDK or create something from scratch